# return avg value in typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I work at an project with typeorm.
In my project I have these entities:
Course.ts

```
export class Course extends DefaultBaseEntity {
    @Column({name: "course_name"})
    courseName: string;
    @Column({name:"discipline"})
    discipline: string;

    @Column({default: 0}) rating: number;
}
```

and RatingsCourse.ts

```
export class CoursesRatings extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({type: "bigint"})
    public id: number;

    // other columns defined here
    @Column({type: "bigint"})
    userId: number;

    @Column({type: 'bigint'}) courseId: number;

    @Column() rating: number;
}
```

the idea it's every course has ratings. when I add a new rating I want to save in the rating field from Course the average ratings value from CoursesRatings
I code something like this :

```
await CoursesRatings.create({
            courseId: ratingBody.courseId,
            userId: user.id,
            rating: ratingBody.rating
        }).save();
        const ratingsObjects = await CoursesRatings.find({
            where: {
                courseId: ratingBody.courseId,
                userId: user.id
            },
            select: ["rating"]
        });
        const ratings: number[] = ratingsObjects.map(x => x.rating);
        const avgRating = ratings.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / ratings.length;
        const course = await Course.findOne(ratingBody.courseId);
        course.rating = Math.fround(avgRating);
        await course.save();
```

but it take some time.
I want to know how to optimize this code. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: How about writing a DB trigger on insert of `CoursesRatings`?

Comment: how to do db trigger? can you show me some code? @SohamLawar

Answer (score 1):

One of the available options for implementing this is creating a database trigger as follows -

```
CREATE TRIGGER computeAvg
AFTER INSERT ON CoursesRatings
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Course
    SET rating = (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM CoursesRatings
                         WHERE CoursesRatings.courseId = Course.id)
    WHERE id = NEW.courseId;
```

If updating the course rating for every insert of user rating proves to be too costly then I would suggest scheduling a CRON job to update the course ratings of all the courses at a specific interval, let us say 1 day. That way it will become less costly in terms of DB operations as compared to the approach earlier suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but for someone that may run into this kind of situation, I believe using a query will solve this.

```
 const avgRating = await this.coursesRatings
    .createQueryBuilder('x')
    .where('x.courseId = :rating', { rating: ratingBody.courseId })
    .select('AVG(rating)', 'avg')
    .getRawOne();
```

With this, you can get access to the average rating, and you have to update `Course`

```
 await this.course.save({
    ...course,
    rate: String(Number(avgRating.avg).toFixed(1)),
  });
```

I believe it helps... The reason I used String is that rating will be a floating type, not an integer.